# Double records inserts when we use button action

Tags: acumatica

When I use new record in the application, I have just one record.
[image]

When I use this code, I have two record.... With only one action.
I have only one TRACE.
[image]

```
#region Button
    public PXAction<POReceipt> generationSSCC;
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Génération des palettes", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    [PXButton(Tooltip = "Génération des palettes")]
```

#endregion

```
 public void GenerationSSCC()
    {
          PXTrace.WriteInformation("EXEMPLE2");
          var une_ligne_sscc = CurrentPOReceiptcolisvue.Insert();  
          une_ligne_sscc.Sscc="AUTOMATIC RECORD";
          une_ligne_sscc.Nbrcolis=134;
          une_ligne_sscc.Poidsnet=134;              
          une_ligne_sscc.Poidsbrut=134;  
          CurrentPOReceiptcolisvue.Update(une_ligne_sscc);  
          
          Base.Save.Press();
          
    }
```

I use this configuration

```
    public
```

`PXSelect<POReceiptcolis,Where<POReceiptcolis.receiptNbr,Equal<Current< POReceiptcolis.receiptNbr>>>> CurrentPOReceiptcolisvue;`

Comment: What is the index on the POReceiptcolis table?  Normally this would happen if you change a value in a key field.  Also, is the view used in your grid CurrentPOReceiptcolisvue?

Comment: Brian, i have :     #region ReceiptNbr
    [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "",IsKey=true)] &     #region Numligne
    [PXDBInt(IsKey=true)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution with this code

```
          POReceiptcolis un_colis= new POReceiptcolis();
          un_colis.Sscc="AUTOMATIC RECORD";
          un_colis.Nbrcolis=134;
          un_colis.Poidsnet=134;              
          un_colis.Poidsbrut=134;
          CurrentPOReceiptcolisvue.Insert(un_colis);
```